# Как сделать, чтобы после клика файл открывался в браузере?

Tags: html

С txt-файла при двойном клике по ссылке начинается скачивание исходного кода страницы. Как сделать, чтобы он просто открывал ссылку в браузере?

Answer (score 1):

Поставить правильный content-type

```
Content-Type: text/plain
```

И убедиться в отсутствии

```
Content-Disposition: attachment
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно прописать правильный атрибут для ссылки.`<a href="2.html" target="_blank">Ссылка откроется в новом окне</a>`